# Can you change ui-grid fonts?

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, angular-ui-grid

Is it possible to change the fonts used in ui-grid? I know out of the box it requires 4 font files: ui-grid.eot, ui-grid.svg, ui-grid.ttf, and ui-grid.woff

I want to use these font files instead: glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot, glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg, glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf, and glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff

I tried just replacing the font files in the ui-grid-unstable.min.css file...however when I do this it breaks the css and I get the "chinese" characters displaying on the grid.

Is it possible to use a different font with ui-grid? Has anyone done this before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research I found this discussion about fonts and ui-grid: https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/2868

I was able to change the default font for my browser and this did change the fonts being used in ui-grid.